# Return value from function and use it

Tags: javascript, function, return

I'm trying to get a value from a function and then use it in other function but I'm not being able to do it...

the first function unidadesTotalCalculate fetches values from two inputs and then multiply them and prints it to an element.

This same function runs 3 times with different elements and then I need to to SUM the result of those three and print it to another element. This is second function, totalBarUpdateStandard().

Can you help me figuring out what is happening? I can't get the value from each function and use it.

```
 function unidadesTotalCalculate(unidadeID, rangeID, print) {
        var value = unidadeID.val();
        var rangevalue = rangeID.val();

        var valueSUM = value * rangevalue;

        jQuery(print).text(valueSUM + '€');
        return valueSUM;

    }


 function totalBarUpdateStandard() {
        var value1 = unidadesTotalCalculate(jQuery('#doenteagudo-standard-dialise-unidades'), jQuery('#doenteagudo-standard-dialise-range'), '#doenteagudo-standard-dialise-total');
        var value2 = unidadesTotalCalculate(jQuery('#doenteagudo-standard-plasma-unidades'), jQuery('#doenteagudo-standard-plasma-range'), '#doenteagudo-standard-plasma-total');
        var value3 = unidadesTotalCalculate(jQuery('#doenteagudo-standard-plasmaferese-unidades'), jQuery('#doenteagudo-standard-plasmaferese-range'), '#doenteagudo-standard-plasmaferese-total');

        var valueTotal = value1 + value2 + value3;

        jQuery('#demo').text(valueTotal + '€');


    }
```

Comment: You've told us what is supposed to happen, but not what actually is happening. What does the HTML look like? What messages are displayed on the Console? What have you done to debug the code? Have you added `console.log` statements to trace the values through the code?

Comment: I've printed it to the element #demo using the

 `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = unidadesTotalCalculate(jQuery('#doenteagudo-standard-dialise-unidades'), jQuery('#doenteagudo-standard-dialise-range'), '#doenteagudo-standard-dialise-total');` 

but it doesn't print anything

Comment: Which brings us back to all the other questions I asked. Have you checked that `jQuery('#demo')` actually matches an element on the page? You need to show us a *complete* reduced [test case](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @msoliman answer did helped me but I was also making the mistake of not calling the function so, double trouble but it's now resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a your solution to your scenario, hope it helps you, I think             `jQuery(print).text(valueSUM + '€');` was the cause of your problem ... it should be jQuery(print).val(valueSUM + '€') .. just put it an static HTML and test it

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input id="doenteagudo-standard-dialise-unidades" value="2" />
<input id="doenteagudo-standard-dialise-range"  value="2"/>
<input id="doenteagudo-standard-dialise-total" />

<input id="doenteagudo-standard-plasma-unidades" value="2" />
<input id="doenteagudo-standard-plasma-range" value="2"/>
<input id="doenteagudo-standard-plasma-total" />


<input id="doenteagudo-standard-plasmaferese-unidades" value="2" />
<input id="doenteagudo-standard-plasmaferese-range" value="2" />
<input id="doenteagudo-standard-plasmaferese-total" />

<div id="demo"></div>

<button id="t"></button>

<script>
function unidadesTotalCalculate(unidadeID, rangeID, print) {
        var value = unidadeID.val();
        var rangevalue = rangeID.val();

        var valueSUM = value * rangevalue;

        jQuery(print).val(valueSUM + '€');
        return valueSUM;

    }


 function totalBarUpdateStandard() {
        var value1 = unidadesTotalCalculate(jQuery('#doenteagudo-standard-dialise-unidades'), jQuery('#doenteagudo-standard-dialise-range'), '#doenteagudo-standard-dialise-total');
        var value2 = unidadesTotalCalculate(jQuery('#doenteagudo-standard-plasma-unidades'), jQuery('#doenteagudo-standard-plasma-range'), '#doenteagudo-standard-plasma-total');
        var value3 = unidadesTotalCalculate(jQuery('#doenteagudo-standard-plasmaferese-unidades'), jQuery('#doenteagudo-standard-plasmaferese-range'), '#doenteagudo-standard-plasmaferese-total');
//console.log(value1);
//console.log(value2);
//console.log(value3);
        var valueTotal = value1 + value2 + value3;

        jQuery('#demo').text(valueTotal + '€');


    }


    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I was also making the mistake of not calling the function so, double trouble but it's now resolved.

Answer (score -1):

you should use val() method of jQuery to get the value of the field.

Thanks